# How to use a user function to fillna() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is a fragment of the dataframe I have:

```
Title | Age     
------+--------
Mr.   | 30
Mr.   | NaN
Mr.   | 32
Mrs.  | 28
Mrs.  | 16
Mr.   | 34
Mrs.  | NaN
```

Edit: I added the last row, to clarify the question

I want to impute the NaNs (second and last row), for the second row, it should use the mean of the other "Mr." in the dataframe, so in this case, should be 32, in the last row it should use the mean of the other "Mrs.", so should be 22

To calculate the mean is as easy as doing

```
value = df.loc[df["Title"] == "Mr."]["Age"].mean()
```

So I wrote a function called agefun:

```
def agefun(df, t):
    return df.loc[df["Title"] == t]["Age"].mean()
```

And it works, now, how can I use this function with the fillna() function? I'd like something like:

```
df['Age'].fillna(agefun(df, this_row_title))
```

But of course it doesn't work, I don't know how to tell the function I like the value corresponding to the Title in that specific row.

How can this be performed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) keeps the same shape as the original series in the dataframe.

```
df['Age'] = df.groupby('Title').transform(lambda group: group.fillna(group.mean()))

>>> df
  Title  Age
0   Mr.   30
1   Mr.   32  # (30 + 32 + 34) / 3 = 32
2   Mr.   32
3  Mrs.   28
4  Mrs.   16
5   Mr.   34
```

In the example above, it keeps all of the values unchanged except for the one `NaN` value on the second row which it fills by calculating the mean for the group, i.e. the mean value of all rows where the `Title` is `Mr.`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked perfectly, but I had to change it to: 

`df['Age'] = df.groupby('Title')["Age"].transform(lambda group: group.fillna(group.mean()))` 

This is because I have some other numerical values on the row. So it looks like it was calculating based on all the numbers in the row

Comment: cool solution! 
any ideas how to implement it to function with custom setting of the agg function? So it could be min() max() median() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df.loc[df['Title'] == 'Mr.', 'Age'].mean())
```

`df` output:

```
   Age Title
0  30.0   Mr.
1  32.0   Mr.
2  32.0   Mr.
3  28.0  Mrs.
4  16.0  Mrs.
5  34.0   Mr.
```

Comment: Nah, that won't work, because if I have a "Mrs." with a NaN it will fill its value with the mean of the "Mr.", thanks a lot!!

Comment: @luisfer See, the problem is that you edited your question after I posted my answer to your original question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for not being more clear in the beginning, I was looking for a more general anwser to impute several missing values, not a specific one, If I was looking for the specific one `df["Age"][2] = 32` would be the direct answer. Thanks!